# defining the same \label twice

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

I'm creating a document (main) in which sections of other documents (others) are often called in. Often the same section of a document (others) is called in at different locations of (main). The problem I have is when using `\label` and `\ref` for cross referencing, the `\label` is rewritten each time the (others) section is called again into (main) because the same `\label` command occurs in a different (further along) section. Is there a way around this?

For example, the code below gives the following image, which is what I don't want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

Hello there.

\ExecuteMetaData[example2]{tag}

\ExecuteMetaData[example2]{tag}

Hello there. 

\end{document}
```

Where the other file, example2 is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\begin{document}

This is some text to fill space. This is some text to fill space.

%<*tag>
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello There}\label{1}
\subsubsection{Hello There, as seen in \ref{1}.}
%</tag>

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where this is what I do want:

[image]

I can't change the label each time because I want to just recall the same document. One solution I thought of would be to have have duplicates of the files being imported with different labels in each of them but I would rather not do that (updating them all would be tedious).

Comment: By "imported" do you mean you copy-and-paste from the file? Or do you use `\input` or `\include`?

Comment: Sorry I will add that to the question. I wasn't using \input or \include but I am using the catchfilebetweentags package to just get specific sections

Comment: Good. Include all the relevant details so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your current (problematic) behaviour.

Comment: @Elijah: Off-topic: labelling with numbers only is not really the best approach

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code provides `\newdocumentimport` that adds a *prefix* to each `\label` and `\ref` (and `\pageref`) that is sequential. That way you call `\newdocumentimport` just before you import a new document and all `\label`s and `\ref`erences will have the added *prefix*. You can also force a fixed prefix using `\setfixedprefix{<prefix>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Counter to keep track of new document imports
\newcounter{newdocumentimport}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldlabel\label% Store \label in \oldlabel
  \let\oldref\ref% Store \ref in \oldref
  \let\oldpageref\pageref% Store \pageref in \oldpageref
}

% Establish a new document import
\newcommand{\newdocumentimport}{%
  \stepcounter{newdocumentimport}%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{\thenewdocumentimport-##1}}%
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{\thenewdocumentimport-##1}}%
  \renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{\oldpageref{\thenewdocumentimport-##1}}%
}
\newcommand{\setfixedprefix}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-##1}}%
  \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-##1}}%
  \renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{\oldpageref{#1-##1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello There}\label{1}
\subsubsection{Hey There, as seen in \ref{1}.}

%same document imported again
\newdocumentimport

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello There}\label{1}
\subsubsection{Hey There, as seen in \ref{1}.}

\end{document}
```

The above option should also work with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), since the storage of `\label`, `\ref` and `\pageref` is delayed until `\AtBeginDocument`.

---

For an automated way of handling *all* files imported using [`catchfilebetweentags`](http://ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags), you can use the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\let\oldExecuteMetaData\ExecuteMetaData
\renewcommand{\ExecuteMetaData}{\newdocumentimport\oldExecuteMetaData}
```

This will prepend `\newdocumentimport` before *every* `\ExecuteMetaData`, allowing your code to remain as-is without having to change anything.