# defining the same \label twice with multiple levels of nested files

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

This question is an extension of the already answered [defining the same \label twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365799/defining-the-same-label-twice). I am trying to find a solution which solves the problem described in [defining the same \label twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365799/defining-the-same-label-twice), while also still allowing cross references between documents called into the main document. For example, see the following three nested files and their output:

First File

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

\section{FIRST FILE}

\subsection{FIRST FILE}\label{arrow}

\subsubsection{FIRST FILE \ref{hey}}

\ExecuteMetaData[example2]{tag}

Call the nested files again.

\ExecuteMetaData[example2]{tag}

\end{document}
```

Second File

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

%<*tag>
\section{SECOND FILE}

\subsection{SECOND FILE}

\subsubsection{SECOND FILE \ref{hey}}

\ExecuteMetaData[example3]{tag}
%</tag>

\end{document}
```

Third File

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

%<*tag>
\section{THIRD FILE}

\subsection{THIRD FILE \ref{arrow}}

\subsubsection{THIRD FILE}\label{hey}
%</tag>

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

What I am looking for is to maintain the ability to cross reference between files 1 and 2 and 3, which works perfectly fine until I call file 2 a second time, resulting in the references in 1.1.1 and 2.1.1 to be 5.1.1 instead of 3.1.1. As mentioned before the solution in [defining the same \label twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365799/defining-the-same-label-twice) solves the issue but not when the files `\ref` a `\label` in other files.

Comment: True, my solution assumes `\label`s and `\ref`erences are local to the file it's called from. You'd need to be able to provide a means to distinguish between a (say) local and global/absolute `\ref`. Without that there's no way for (La)TeX to know whether `\ref{hey}` could refer to something internal, or possibly external to the current file. Don't know whether you're able to edit the different files and use an alternative to `\ref`, say, `\absref`...?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking as well. What I had done earlier today after posting this is define a \newcounter{counter}, then define \newcommand{\callcount}{\arabic{counter}}. So in each \ref which I wanted to be "local" I put \ref{\callcount something}, and global \ref s are just written as normal. So as long as I write something along the lines of \addtocounter{counter}{1} before inputting a redundant file the referencing seems to work. As you mentioned there really is no way around having to distinguish between the two label types somehow.

Comment: Using `\callout` is exactly what my other answer does automatically, but for *all* `\ref`s. (La)TeX cannot do all the thinking for you, so you either have to insert some *global* `\ref`s manually, or insert the *local* `\ref`s manually, or define some mechanism by which you can discern between local/global `\ref`erences.