# "multiply defined labels" error when combining different tex files

Tags: labels, multiple-files

I am currently trying to write a book containing multiple chapters, with each chapter saved in a separate tex file.  In each chapter, I have similar sections with label "sec:introduction", "sec:methods", "sec:conclusions", etc.  When combining these chapters with `\input` command, I got error message saying labels are "multiply defined".  I am wondering if it is possible to somehow let latex compiler realize that they are in different files and will not conflict with each other in any references (denoted by `\ref`)?  I know changing these labels altogether would be a choice, but there are other multiply defined labels related to equations, figures, etc which could take a while to fix.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: each label should be unique!

Comment: @Zarko Right, I am wondering if there is similar mechanism to C++ namespace, where there could be multiple same labels, but in different  "namespace"s (meaning different files).

Comment: it should be easy enough to do a one-off edit to change `\label{` and `\ref{` to `\label{x` and `\ref{x`  in a document so that document has a unique set of labels starting x it should just be a single edit in your editor it doesn't matter how many things are labelled

Comment: In theory it would be possible to add a wrapper around `\input` that locally redefines `\label` and `\ref` to be unique. The downside is that you can't `\ref` `\label`s from a different file. (I didn't know good search terms here, but I think something like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365799/35864.) But a search-and-replace to make sure the labels are unique in the source is probably the best way here.

Comment: A slightly simpler version of the idea I linked above: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517729/35864

Comment: @moewe This is really awesome!  Thank you so much!